# Mysql / WordPress killing my server with 80k users

Tags: query, mysql, performance, server-load

I have recently installed wordpress in a production server with **80K fields in wp_users** registered, 175K fields in wp_post table and 350K fields in wp_postmeta. Problem is that mysql database is consuming all CPU and getting server too slow. I disabled all plugings and renamed those plugins folders and problem persists.

```
top - 20:26:55 up 6 days, 16:01,  1 user,  load average: 4.42, 4.47, 4.54
Tasks: 192 total,   2 running, 190 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 55.2 us,  3.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 40.7 id,  0.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32639948 total,   239032 free,  8069912 used, 24331004 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8388604 total,  8375548 free,    13056 used. 23506600 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3957 mysql     20   0 1629756 232200   9344 S 384.1  0.7 106:23.68 mysqld
```

I have monitored mysql with  mysql -u admin -p -e "SHOW full PROCESSLIST;" and gets repeated many times this same query:

```
| 13489 | mydbnumber1| localhost | mydbnumber1 | Query   |    0 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT wp_users.user_login FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND (
  (
    ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%\"administrator\"%' )
  )
) ORDER BY user_login ASC |    0.000 |
```

I have looked for this killer code query into all files of wordpress instalation and only found match in the file named: \wp-admin\includes\deprecated.php line 523. So I decided to comment that pece of code and upload back file deprecated.php to server, but problem persists!

This is crazy now, I have been now 2 days investigating this and I can not find a solution.

Comment: I don't know what `um-followers` is but whichever plugin is responsible for it is running super expensive queries. You'll need to disable the plugin or have the plugin author correct the issue, speak with their support routes. A very basic search for "um-followers wordpress" implies it's the ultimate members plugin

Comment: um-followers is a plugin, but key is that I disabled even that plugin, renamed it folder and restarted mysql and killers queries appear again. Thank you.

Comment: They may be different queries then, it's not possible to tell just from descriptions alone. Do what I did and google the keys that are being queried for. Eitherway WP on its own should be able to handle those numbers of fields, the problem comes when you add plugins that query post meta or user meta

Comment: SOLUTION: I finally found what was generationg so many queries like this and killing server: Copying to tmp table | SELECT wp_users.user_login FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND (  (    ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%\"administrator\"%' )  ) ) ORDER BY user_login ASC . All these queries where generated by plugin "WP Fastest Cache". I supose it cant handle to cache my 300k pages website.I removed plugin and installed another cache plugin. I hopes this helps any other with  same problem. Thanks

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis. We will help you 'Make Every Moment Count'.

Comment: @weeb10        How are you doing with performance at this time?  Posting additional information requested on Jul 22, 2019, would allow analysis to suggest Global Variable changes to improve performance.

Comment: I've just finished a free plugin to handle this exact problem.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-users-for-speed/. Root cause of slowdown: WordPress's way of finding editor, administrator, other user roles doesn't scale up gracefully to tens of thousands of registered users.